# Unity CaptureScreenshot captures and editor as well

Tags: unity, c#, screenshot

I'm trying to create some screenshots but `ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot` actually captures the entire editor and not just the Game view. 
[image: error]

I'm using this few lines of code here:

```
public class ScreenShotTaker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public KeyCode takeScreenshotKey = KeyCode.S;
    public int screenshotCount = 0;
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(takeScreenshotKey))
        {
            ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot("Screenshots/"
                 + "_" + screenshotCount + "_"+ Screen.width + "X" + Screen.height + "" + ".png");
            Debug.Log("Screenshot taken.");
        }
    }
}
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Took a look at it and it's actually a Unity bug, filed a report, see where it goes.

There are methods that rely on `RenderTextures` but they don't capture the UI. 
In the meantime, I asked this on Stack Overflow as well and got some handy answer that saves all pixel info from the screen like so:

```
public KeyCode takeScreenshotKey = KeyCode.S;
public int screenshotCount = 0;

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(takeScreenshotKey))
    {
        StartCoroutine(captureScreenshot());
    }
}

IEnumerator captureScreenshot()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    string path = "Screenshots/"
             + "_" + screenshotCount + "_" + Screen.width + "X" + Screen.height + "" + ".jpeg";

    Texture2D screenImage = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height);
    //Get Image from screen
    screenImage.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);
    screenImage.Apply();
    //Convert to png
    byte[] imageBytes = screenImage.EncodeToPNG();

    //Save image to file
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, imageBytes);
}
```

Note that this script though works, it has to be modified for the sake of convenience. It also worths mentioning that if you use `Outline` on your UI elements, those will become transparent if saved as `.png`, so I used `.jpeg` instead.